# How to control where the canvas is placed in the document?

Tags: canvas, emscripten, emcc

I have a C++ application with a UI that I converted to JS using emcc.

The UI of this application takes the form of a canvas on the web page and is appended to the body. How can I control where the canvas is appended?

What if I want the canvas to be appended to `#my-container` instead of the body?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From default output html file,
you will got this code with building command with -o arg (for example):

```js
 emcc source.c ... -o myapp/index.html
```

```css
.emscripten { padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; }
div.emscripten { text-align: center; }      
div.emscripten_border { border: 1px solid black; }
/* the canvas *must not* have any border or padding, or mouse coords will be wrong */
canvas.emscripten { border: 0px none; background-color: black; }
```

Also interest point:

```html
<div class="emscripten_border">
 <canvas class="emscripten"
         id="canvas"
         oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"
         tabindex=-1 >
 </canvas>
</div>
```

I inspect canvas container relations, there is no any problems there. You can manipulate
with canvas vs container in any directions.

Dont worry emscripten use id="canvas" arg no miss.

Be carefully when you giving width and height to your canvas elem.

It is a different effect on graphics in next example ->

```html
<canvas style="width:100%"></canvas>
```

```html
<canvas width="100%"></canvas>
```

It is little complicated to use c,c++ in that proporse. If you really want then better for begin take a look reference link => https://github.com/mbasso/asm-dom

Example :

**One way :**

```html
 <button onclick="_callFunction()">
```

```js
// callback for button event
extern "C"
{
    void callFunction() { std::cout << "callFunction called \n"; }
}
```

// Other way

```
emscripten_run_script("document.getElementById('canvas').width =
 '320'");


// compile 
emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_callFunction']"
```

Test with debugger next link:

[something.html](https://maximumroulette.com/applications/c-cpp-to-javascript/c-cpp-to-javascript/deriv-gles/build/something.html)